# hint for automorphism group of Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, automorphism-group

I am studying about automorphism group of simply connected surfaces.
My reference book is "Dynamics in One Complex Variable" by John Milnor.
In page 5, automorphism group of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (Riemann sphere), called $\mathcal{G} ( \hat{\mathbb{C}} )$ is introduced.

There, for $g \in \mathcal{G} ( \hat{\mathbb{C}} )$ with $g(0) = 0$ and $g(\infty) = \infty$, he states that $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ is bounded!

But its boundedness is not clear for me. Could anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Which part is unclear to you? That $g(z)/z$ tends to a finite (non-zero) value for $z\to 0$, that it tends to a finite value for $z \to \infty$, or that both together imply that $g(z)/z$ is bounded?

Comment: The boundedness for every $z \in \hat{\mathbb{C}}$.